# Handler method is slow on new devices

Tags: java, android

I have a simple method running inside a handler. I am populating numbers using an array adapter. My code take more time to run on newer devices with Android 6 or higher, as oppose to old ones.

Here is part of my code, CCA is derived from ArrayAdapter:

```
numbersToRun = amount;
            myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (numbersToRun > 0) {
                        boolean isInt2 = IsIntegerOnly.isChecked();
                        if (isInt2) {
                            int n = Rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
                            String Str = n + "";
                            RandomData.add(Str);
                            CCA.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            RandomsList.setSelection(CCA.getCount() - 1);
                        } else {
                            double d = min + (max - min) * Rnd.nextDouble();
                            String Str = String.format("%.4f", d) + "";
                            RandomData.add(Str);
                            CCA.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            RandomsList.setSelection(CCA.getCount() - 1);

                        }
                        numbersToRun--;
                        myHandler.postDelayed(this, new Double(interval*1000).longValue());
                    } else {
                        myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                    }

                }
            },  0);
```

Do I need to run garbage collection here?

What can I do in order to get good performance on stronger and newer devices?

Comment: so what takes the most time? did you try to [profile your Handler code](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html)?

Comment: I tested my code / app on some devices. On my friend's phone with LG and Android 4 or 4.4 just placing 30 numbers in the list made a difference. In my Samsung S7 it took 2+ seconds and even more.

Comment: so why do you use `postDelayed`? did you use any profiling tools? what actually do you want to achieve with that handler code?

Comment: The user can select a time interval for the numbers population. I can't figure out why on my device it's so slow.

Comment: try `postAtTime` instead of `postDelayed`, or use `delayMillis = interval*1000 - time_spent_in_handler's_code`

Comment: Will that work on every phone? Why will this improve the performance?